# WPF Textbox placeholder and multiple data triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a placeholder for a TextBox and this is what I have so far.

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="Field" Tag="{Binding Key}" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" LostFocus="Field_LostFocus" GotFocus="Field_GotFocus"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Optional" Foreground="LightGray" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="10 5 0 0">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TinyText}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Field, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

How can I make it so that when the focus is in the TextBox the placeholder is also collapsed?

Comment: Check the textbox's `IsKeyboardFocused` property.

Comment: Or `IsFocused` property if you want to include the case of logical focus.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `DataTrigger` that triggers on the `IsKeyboardFocused` property:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="Field" Tag="{Binding Key}" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Optional" Foreground="LightGray" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="10 5 0 0">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Field, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Field, Path=IsKeyboardFocused}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How about if this in part of an ItemsControl and there is a property called IsMandatory which also needs to be tested for? If this flag is true then never display the "Optional" placeholder amongst the other logic?

Comment: Add another `DataTrigger` then?